# Magento 1 - Logging only works in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, log, logging

I am unable to log anything in the frontend. I added the following code in the `index.php`, just below `Mage::run`:

```
Mage::Log('test from index.php', 7, 'test.log');
```

It is successfully logged if I reload the backend, but not if I reload the frontend? Why?

Logging is activated under `System -> Configuration -> Developer Options -> Log Settings`.

I set the permissions of the folder var recursively to 777 (chmod -R 777 var/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch the storeview in the backend and activate the log there.

Answer (score 1):

try with `Mage::log('test from index.php', 7, 'test.log', true);`
Notice the last parameter `true`. This will force the log.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  But I found the real cause. I had to switch the storeview in the backend and activate the log there.